# use of Scapy to generate network load on mininet

Tags: python, scapy, network-traffic, mininet, sdn

I am doing research on SDN using mininet, however i have to generate specific traffic load on the links by parsing a txt file in python, since Scapyhttp://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/ gives python API for send packets over network. but i could not found good tutorial about Scapy Python API, and functions to start with. I have 105 switches and about 200 links in them, i have to generate  specific load on each link.

can anyone please guide me how to achieve this goal?

Thanks,

Comment: `Scapy`'s documentation can be found [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/index.html) and its API [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf).

Comment: I have gone through both links before but its not much helpful for a beginner like me since API pdf is almost empty, contains heading and rest of the thing is blank.

Comment: I think that the [documentation's interactive tutorial](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#interactive-tutorial) is a good place to start.

Comment: For this infrastructure I would use 'iperf'. It's light and low level tool for network packets generation, with a lot of options, such as Bi-directional bandwidth measurement.

iperf -c 10.1.1.1 -r

iperf -s

Here is the link: http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php

Comment: Another option is use ftp client/ftp/http servers to transfer some large files around. pyftplib is easily scriptable from commandline or call from bash script, sample for simplehttp or simplehttps server